# WMI management scope connect to local instead of remote

Tags: c#, wmi

I tried to connect to a remote PC and query for its processes but when I run the code, it got connected with my local PC and obtained its processes instead of the remote PC.
The code is

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\remote-user\\root\\cimv2");
scope.Connect();
ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
```

Comment: If the answers solved your problem, please mark them accordingly. Otherwise, more details will be needed (what went wrong this time etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be passing a username ("remote-user") instead of a hostname of the remote machine to your management scope. Change your code to e.g.:

```
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
options.Password = "remoteUserPassword"; // you may want to avoid plain text password and use SecurePassword property instead
options.Username = "remote-user"; 
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\remoteMachineHostname\root\cimv2", options);
```

Answer (score 0):

(I assume that remote-user is Full computer name) change:

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\remote-user\\root\\cimv2");
```

to:

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\<FullComputerName>\root\cimv2");
```

another option:

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\<FullComputerName>\\root\\cimv2");
```

See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms257337%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) link (it's Microsoft example)

**Edit**

if you want to connect with deffrent user you need to pass ConnectionOptions (see above link)